# xml data island doesn't work

Tags: html, xml

I've got a simple xml document `main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<students>
<student>
    <name>Name1</name>
    <surname>Surname1</surname>
</student>
<student>
    <name>Name2</name>
    <surname>Surname2</surname>
</student>
<student>
    <name>Name3</name>
    <surname>Surname3</surname>
</student>
</students>
```

Also I've got a html page `main.html` where I want to show data from xml file.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test XML</title>
</head>
<body>
    <xml id="students" src="main.xml"></xml>
    <table id="table" datasrc="#students" border="1">
        <thead>
            <th>Student name</th>
            <th>Student surname</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <td><span datafld="name"></span></td>
            <td><span datafld="surname"></span></td>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

But it doesn't work - It shows only head of the table. Also both files are in the same folder. Why?

I'm using Windows 7 and IE8

Comment: As a side note, [XML data islands have been deprecated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh801224.aspx).

Comment: @GSerg, I know but my exam questions do not agree with me :lol:

Comment: You definitely have some <tr>'s missing around those <th>'s and <td>'s. That *might* help....

Comment: @robnick indeed. now it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The case is solved: I forgot tag `tr` before `td`s.